# Unity Raycasting does not work with imported object (meshcollider is generated)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have imported a surface which I modeled with 'blender', I imported it with mesh collider. When I want to do a ray casting on this surface to place random objects it won't work. When I set a standard plane above this surface, the ray casting works on this plane. So I think my modeled surface isn't catching the ray casting, but I don't know why. Can anybody help me?

```
void Start ()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        //What we will spawn
        GameObject objectToSpawn = objectsToSpawn[Random.Range(0,objectsToSpawn.Length)];

        Vector2 spawnPositionV2 = Random.insideUnitCircle*spawnRadius;

        Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(spawnPositionV2.x,0.0f,spawnPositionV2.y);

        Vector3 transformOffsetSpawnPosition = transform.position+spawnPosition;

        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast (transformOffsetSpawnPosition, Vector3.down, out hit)) {

            Vector3 finalSpanPosition = hit.point;
            Instantiate (objectToSpawn, finalSpanPosition, Quaternion.identity);

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mesh collider you should set 'Convex' property to true in order to make it work with collisions. I believe it's actual for raycasting as well.
Also you can enter collider editing mode and check if mesh surface is covered by collider correctly.

Comment: if it check convex is works, but now my trees and character a literally floating an walking 10 feet above my surface. The collider isn't as detailed as before... Can I fix this?

Comment: You can fix this by setting colliders up in a right way) Try to select all the objects in the scene in runtime, toggle Gizmos on and expand collider component to see colliders graphics in scene view. If some object is floating above another while it should be standing right on it, then there is something wrong with collider (check its size and constraints) or with rigidbody attached to it (mass, gravity, non-kinematic). Provide more info about your scene and colliders settings if you checked out all this settings and it still doesn't work.